# CSS Layout - 3 column with stretchy background

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I am building a 3 column fluid layout, and have gotten 90% the way there. I am wondering on what is the best way to impliment the background, or side bars - however you want to look at it.

[image]

I have a good box hack that centers my main content area, and now I need to impliment the two stripes you see on either side that has a small 1px border on the respective inside border.

I could create a 1px high stripe that is 1000's of pixels wide, but I have a feeling there is a much better way to do this - possibly with pure CSS?

Am I now looking at a 5 column layout here, or is this still a three column fluid?

If anyone can provide a good pattern or link for this style of layout (its probably the most common out there nowadays, huh?) I'd really appricaite it!

Here is my current fluid wrap code:

css:

```
body
    {
        margin: 10px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #siteWrapper
    {
        width: 980px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="siteWrapper">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Here is a link to that image above to make it easier to read: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aRw8T.jpg

Comment: http://www.manisheriar.com/holygrail/index.htm could work for you

Comment: Yes, that seems like it coudl be modified to fit my needs; if I am able to set the width of the inner box. I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body
{
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background: whatevercolor;
}
 #siteWrapper
    {
        width: 980px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-left: whatever;
        border-right: whatever;
    }
```

Comment: assuming he doesn't want any content inside the sidebars??

Comment: No content inside the sidebars, but they should grow (?) yes, I am pretty sure that is the case. What is the best practice for this layout (seems like it'd be very common...)